# How to configure tsconfig.json to output files from multiple source folders to single flat outDir?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have multiple typescript *projects* (e.g. `client` and `server`), which share some common functionality (located in a `common` folder). Consider this folder structure:

```
+ client
|  - tsconfig.json
|  + src
|     - client.ts
+ common
   + src
      - util.ts
```

Where the `client.ts` imports the utility this way:

```
import { Util } from '../../common/src/util';
```

For brevity I am omitting the `server` folder, which is at the same level as `client`. After the transpilation into the `out` folder, I would like to get this simple flat folder structure:

```
+ client
|  + out
|     - client.js
|     - util.js
```

... and ideally I could simply import the common utility agnostic of the actual folder:

```
import { Util } from './util';
```

How do I configure the `tsconfig.json` to achieve that?

I tried different combinations of `rootDirs`, `baseUrl` and `paths`, but I am still getting the `client` and `common` subfolders (both even including their `src` subfolder) under `out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And now we have the support for project references in Typescript 3.0 (i.e. cascade build of multiple Typescript projects). We can also control the output location of the `tsc` builds.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/07/30/announcing-typescript-3-0/#project-references

If a Typescript project 'bar' *uses* project 'foo', here is how you chain them:

```
// ./src/bar/tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // Needed for project references.
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,

        // Other options...
        "outDir": "../../lib/bar",
        "strict": true, "module": "esnext", "moduleResolution": "node",
    },
    "references": [
        { "path": "../foo" }
    ]
}
```

Thanks, TS guys!

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can't.

I am in a situation similar to yours, I have looked around but it seems like there is no way to change this behaviour with TypeScipt configuration.

The best you can do is use something else (a Grunt task, a shell script, ...) for moving the js files and deleting the generated folders, after every build.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem in my current project (which has the same setup) by putting a link to the common lib into both sources.

```
common/
  src/
    lib/
client/
  src/
    lib/ -> $PROJECT_PATH/common/src/lib/
server/
  src/
    lib/ -> $PROJECT_PATH/common/src/lib/
```

Compilation and bundling become transparent as the tools treat that directory as a local one.

Comment: As I explore the other options, this is slowly starting to appear to me as the best option. So sad.