# Tsconfig, How to flatten structure src files at build to dist, when I use multiple rootDirs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have nest js app with type orm and files database migrations. Actual for Windows.
I need to make flatten structure from src to build dist and then add folder migrations.
I have this struct:

```
project/
  tsconfig.json
  tsconfig.build.json
  ormconfig.js
  migrations/
    **.file.ts
  src/
    app.module.ts
    main.ts
    common/
    modules/
```

I need to build:

```
dist
  migrations/
  common/
  modules/
  app.module.d.ts
  app/module.js
  main.d.ts
  main.js
```

But I have:

```
dist
  migrstions/
  src/
  tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "rootDirs": ["./src/*"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

My ormconfig.js

```
module.exports = {
  type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  entities: ['src/**/entities/index.ts'],
  migrations: ['migrations/*.ts'],
  migrationsRun: false,
  synchronize: false,
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'migrations',
  },
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
};
```

T try to add path in tsconfig: (by solution [How to configure tsconfig.json to output files from multiple source folders to single flat outDir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995801/how-to-configure-tsconfig-json-to-output-files-from-multiple-source-folders-to-s)), but it does not work for me.

```
"compilerOptions": {
   ...
   "rootDir": "./src",
   "paths": {
      "@app/migrations": ["./migrations"]
    }
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to configure tsconfig for such a structure, or the only solution is to transfer the migrations folder to src?

Comment: Have you tried removing `"rootDirs": ["./src/*"]` from your tsconfig?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use this config, but the result is the same.
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}`