# Configure a TypeScript project with common dependencies to build multiple plain JavaScript output files

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I'm currently writing [some scripts](https://github.com/mizzao/bot.land) for [Bot Land](http://bot.land). Bot Land is a real-time strategy game where instead of controlling your units with a mouse and keyboard, you write code to control your bots via an API, and then your bots go fight others' bots. If you're familiar with units in SC2, you can create bots that are similar to blink stalkers, siege tanks, medics, and ultralisks. (It's quite a fun game for software engineers, but that's outside the scope of this question.)

[image: bot land]

Bot control has three levels of increasing complexity: a default AI, a [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/)-like programming language, and a reduced set of JavaScript called BotLandScript. Although the built-in editor for BotLandScript is reasonable, you have to upload all your code as **one single file** with global top-level functions everywhere. Naturally, this starts getting painful after a while if your code starts to get long and different bots share the same functions.

[image: programming environment]

To facilitate writing code for multiple bots, reduce the chance for unintentional errors when coding in bare JS, and increase my chances of beating other players, I set up the [above TypeScript project](https://github.com/mizzao/bot.land) to provide a common library as well as code for each of my bots. The current directory structure looks like approximately like the following:

```
lib/ 
  bot.land.d.ts
  common.ts
BlinkStalker/
  BlinkStalker.ts
  tsconfig.json
Artillery/
  Artillery.ts
  tsconfig.json
SmartMelee/
  SmartMelee.ts
  tsconfig.json
```

`lib` is the common code that is shared among bots, and provides TypeScript definitions for the (non-TS) Bot Land API. Each bot then gets its own folder, with one file containing the bot code and the other a boilerplate `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es3",
    "module": "none",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outFile": "bot.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "MissileKite.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../lib/**/*"
  ]
}
```

When each `tsconfig.json` is built, it creates a corresponding `bot.js` that contains transpiled code from the bot itself as well as *all* the code in `common.js`. This setup is suboptimal for a few reasons, among others: it requires a lot of duplicate boilerplate, makes it hard to add new bots, includes a lot of unnecessary code for each bot, and requires each bot to be built separately.

However, based on [my research so far](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46995801/586086), it doesn't seem like there's an easy way to do what I want. In particular, using the new `tsc -b` option and references does not work, because that requires the code to be modularized and Bot Land requires a single file with all functions defined at the top level.

What's the best way to achieve as many of the following as possible?

- No new boilerplate required to add a new bot (e.g. no `tsconfig.json` per bot)
- Use `import` for common functions to avoid outputting unused code, but then...
- Still output all functions as one single file in Bot Land's specific format
- A single build step that produces multiple output files, one for each bot
- Bonus: integrating the build process with VS Code. There is a currently correspondingly boilerplate [`tasks.json`](https://github.com/mizzao/bot.land/blob/master/.vscode/tasks.json) for building each sub-project.

I vaguely surmise the answer probably involves something like Grunt in addition to `tsc`, but I don't know enough about that to be sure.

Comment: Is necessary that all bots have separate folders? Or is it enough that each bot is on the root level in a single file? (e.g `<root>/MissileKite.ts`)

Comment: Do all transpiled bot-files must be named `bot.js`?

Comment: Root in a single file would be preferable; they are in separate folders because of the separate `tsconfig.json`. Transpiled bot files can be named anything, preferably the .js version of the original file. I have it set up this way now in the repo outputting to `build/MissileKite.js`.

Comment: @andrew-mao You can give a look a my template for GAS projects which addresses most of your requirements (but targeting a different environment) If it suits you, I might be able to adapt it for you sometime next week. https://github.com/PopGoesTheWza/ts-gas-project-starter

Comment: Is `tsconfig-gas.json` the relevant thing to look at there?

Comment: @AndrewMao in my repo, `tsconfig-gas.json` is just common `tsc` settings for producing GAS compatible JavaScript and is included by project settings like `/src/GasProject1/tsconfig.json`. GasProject1 for example is set to produce a single `.js` file without requiring any third party dependencies like Webpack. Since @jperl already provided you with an answer, just let me know if it suits your need or if you want me to setup a `bot-land` template project.

Comment: @AndrewMao BTW, TS build mode does not requires the typescript source to be modularized (though it makes little sense if not) but even with modularized `.ts` source, you can set `outFile` and generate a single `.js` (like `/src/GasProject1/tsconfig.json` does)

Comment: But in that case, does that generate a file of the format with all functions defined at the top level, or is it a janky mumbo jumbo of IIFEs and other "module-looking" things?

Comment: @AndrewMao in simple configuration, all `.ts` files are just concatenated. If you want IIFE / closure for code isolation and such, I usually use typescript `namespace` for that. Just let me know if you have more question, and if interested if I should put up a repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my [attempt](https://github.com/PopGoesTheWza/bot.land) to answer your requirements.

Notable files:

- `src/tsconfig-botland.json` holds settings for any *bot.land* script (including your custom declarations which I moved to `types/bot-land/index.d.ts`). You may which to change the `strict` settings I used.
- `src/tsconfig.json` holds references to all your bots. This is the file to edit whenever you want to add another bot script

A bot script is at least two files: a minimalist `tsconfig.json` and one or more `.ts` script files.

For example `src/AggroMiner/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-botland",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outFile": "../../build/AggroMiner.js"
    },
    "files": ["index.ts"],
    "include": ["**/*.ts", "../lib/**/*.ts"]
}
```

In most cases, to start a new bot script you should:

1. copy any bot folder (i.e. `src/AggroMiner`) to a new folder under `src`
2. edit the `src/<newBotFolder>/tsconfig.json` to edit the `outFile` with the name of your bot
3. edit `src/tsconfig.json` and add a reference to `src/<newBotFolder>`

The following `npm`/`yarn` script have been set:

- `build` to build all bots
- `build-clean` which clear the `build` folder before running a `build`
- `format` to run Prettier on all `.ts` files under `src`
- `lint` to run a tslint check on all bot scripts

Now running down your requirements:

- No new boilerplate required to add a new bot (e.g. no tsconfig.json per bot)

To achieve this would require creating some script which would enumerate your bots folder/scripts... and setup the relevant per bot `tsconfig.json` and run `tsc`. Unless it is strictly necessary, a minimal setup (describe above) might be sufficient.

- Use import for common functions to avoid outputting unused code, but then...

First, be aware that if you start using any module `export`/`import` statements, you will need additional 3rd party to pack / treeshake in order to achieve a single file output. From what I could gather of Bot.land, your scripts are running on the server. Unless deadcode has an impact on your bot performance, I would not really bother.

- Still output all functions as one single file in Bot Land's specific format

Done.

- A single build step that produces multiple output files, one for each bot

Done.

- Bonus: integrating the build process with VS Code. There is a currently correspondingly boilerplate tasks.json for building each sub-project.

The `npm` scripts should appear in vsc's tasks list (at least they do in mine) thus making the `tasks.json` unnecessary.

Comment: Deadcode is a fine compromise for everything else you made here; can you let me know though why you used `types/bot-land` for the definitions and why you chose `strict` settings?

Comment: Types/bot-land/index.d.ts really is your original .d.ts from lib, renamed and placed differently. Î assume it sort of describe the general bot.land execution context for all scripts and thus I make sure it is always available in every bot script. The ‘strict’ settings are only here because I lazily copied my favored settings (same for the prettier settings). Those should be adapted to the user (you) preference.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's a customary reason to put that into `types` or if that was just a specific way to organize that you picked.

Comment: The only reason is that assuming it was the bot.land context. Think of it like having the @types/node typings already available in your nodejs scripts

Comment: So, is `types` the convention for a place to import types, does it have a special meaning? Or you can call it whatever you want?

Comment: A /types folder is one of the conventional places where one puts external types declarations (I.e. specific execution context like the botland engine or untyped JavaScript modules/packages, which are not used here)

Comment: You have a link to your repo in the above answer, but you deleted it :-(

Comment: @AndrewMao My bad... I still had a local copy and just republished it.

Comment: Thanks. It will be good for people who happen upon this question later and want to see your work.

Answer (score 3):

You could actually use project references. Follow these steps to get the same results you were getting for your original files, with all functions at the top level in one file. However, I could not find a solution to import only needed functions in bots. That is, without using imports and exports.

In your  tsconfig.json at the root

```
{
    "files": [],
    "references": [
        { "path": "./lib" }
        { "path": "./AggroMiner" }
        { "path": "./ArtilleryMicro" }
        { "path": "./MissileKite" }
        { "path": "./SmartMelee" }
        { "path": "./ZapKite" }
    ]
}
```

Next, in your lib folder, add a tsconfig.json like so

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "composite": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outFile": "../build/lib.js",
    "target": "es3",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
  },
  "files": [
    "data.ts",
    "movement.ts",
    "utils.ts"
  ]
}
```

We need to make a few adjustments in data.ts, movement.ts and utils.ts so that ts doesn't bother us with compilation errors.

data.ts

```
/// <reference path="./bot.land.d.ts"/>

(...)
```

movement.ts

```
/// <reference path="./data.ts"/>
/// <reference path="./utils.ts"/>
(...)
```

utils.ts

```
/// <reference path="./bot.land.d.ts"/>
(...)
```

Next, we add base.json at the root (the tsconfig.json of the bots will extend it).

base.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "composite": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "target": "es3",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
  }
}
```

and the bots' tsconfig.json (adapt according to bots)

```
{
  "extends": "../base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outFile": "../build/AggroMiner.js",
  },
  "files": [
    "AggroMiner.ts"
  ],
  "references": [
      { "path": "../lib", "prepend": true } //note the prepend: true
  ]
}
```

That's it. Now just run

```
tsc -b
```

Comment: So I thought of something like this, but the reason it doesn't work is because the file that gets output on your branch has a bunch of stuff like this at the top, and the game needs one file with all the functions in it. So I'd then have to manually cobble all the compiled outputs together to create the file that I'd upload, instead of just copy pasting the file.
`
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var data_1 = require("../lib/data");
var movement_1 = require("../lib/movement");
var utils_1 = require("../lib/utils");
`

Comment: But it works since lib is also output (built) in the build folder (thanks to the references).

Comment: I was in the process of editing my comment - see above. Or take a look at the `build/MissileKite.js` that is outputted when you build the original repo.

Comment: @AndrewMao sorry, only now I understand what you meant by " because that requires the code to be modularized and Bot Land requires a single file with all functions defined at the top level.". I thought about using "prepend: true" but that requires using outFile and ts won't let us compile the files in lib since some are dependent on others.

Comment: @AndrewMao I've added Webpack support. I edited the post and pushed the changes on the repo. Let me know if it's better.

Comment: It's true now that all the required functions are in one file (great!) but however, they are still each compiled as a module starting with `(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__)` and would require a bunch of postprocessing to get to what was there before.

Take a look at one of the original files after doing a `tsc`...do you see the format? Is there any way to get it to look like that?

Comment: @AndrewMao some functions must be globally available, is that so? Then maybe global.update could do the trick. in the ts file (before it's compiled with Webpack) you do: `global.update = update` or whatever functions you want to expose.

Comment: @AndrewMao Else, I guess I've run out of ideas.. Sorry.

Comment: The code is actually run in a restricted environment, hence how it's generated in a strange way. I actually strip out all the `var =` as part of the build process in order for it to be acceptable. Thanks though, I think I can adapt some of what you've written to simplify the build.

Comment: @jperl if you follow the `module` route, you'll never be able to achieve the *single file* target without some 3rd party webpack/gulp/parcel/whatever. There is at least two ways to simply "concatenate" your `.ts` files at compile time: Either with `references...prepend` or with `include` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @PopGoesTheWza Yes, I know about prepend. A few comments above I said 'I thought about using "prepend: true" but that requires using outFile and ts won't let us compile the files in lib since some are dependent on others.'.

Comment: @jperl I was too lazy to setup `prepend=true` in this bot repo. If you're interested though, you can have a look at the repository for GAS (Google Apps Script) which I mentioned in a comment on the original question.

Comment: @PopGoesTheWza thanks man. I was getting compilation errors when using prepend but I found using triple slash directives makes it work fine.

Comment: @AndrewMao if you're still interested in project references, I got it working with a few adjustements. I've edited my post.

Comment: @jperl Give a look at my answer. It use `typeRoot` and `types` to automatically add the bot.land `.d.ts` from the common `tsconfig.json` thus saving in-context triple slash reference for custom types

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200875/discussion-between-popgoesthewza-and-jperl).